# Elliptic regularity in $L^1$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

Dear all,

I am looking for a good reference for elliptic regularity in $L^1$. To be more precise

Let $\Omega\subset\mathrm{R}^n$ be a bounded smooth domain, let $A$ be a properly elliptic differential operator in $\Omega$ and let $B$ be a first order differential operator on $\partial\Omega$ satisfying the complementing condition. For $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ consider the problem

$$Au=f, \mbox{ in }\Omega,\qquad Bu=0, \mbox{ on }\partial\Omega.$$

It seems to be well-known that there is at least a weak solution $u\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$. Is it possible to give a reference for this? Is it possible to state more regularity for $u$?

I would be very grateful for any useful hints on this problem.

Richard

Comment: Given $u\in W^{1,1}$, how do you define $B u|_{\partial \Omega}$?

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference where elliptic equations in L1 are dealt with: Tanabe, "Functional analytical methods for partialdifferential equations" There it is also explained in what way the boundary values are to be understood.

Comment: Can you  be more specific with this reference (journal, year of publication). I cannot seem to find  the reference on MathSciNet

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Functional-Analytic-Differential-Equations-Mathematics/dp/0824797744

Answer (score 0):

Give a look vere http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X9290285L where Poisson type equation with f in some particular subclass of L1 is studied.